# std::bad_cast from parent to child?

Tags: c++, casting

For simplicity,

```
class Parent {}
class Child1 : Parent {}
class Child2 : Parent {}
```

Elsewhere, I created instances of Child1 and Child2 and store it in same vector under Parent:

```
// . . . in .h file, for example
vector<Parent> vector_of_parent;

// . . . in one particular method
Child1 c1; 
Child2 c2; 
vector_of_parent.push_back(c1);
vector_of_parent.push_back(c2);
// . . .
```

Then in another method which has access to `vector_of_parent`, I tried

```
 void doSomething(Parent& some_child) { 
 // wrapped in a try block somehow...
 Child1& c = dynamic_cast<Child1&> some_child;
 // do something if the cast is successful
 }

 void otherMethod() {
      doSomething(vector_of_parent.at(0)); // vector_of_parent.at(0) is a Child1
 }
```

Why is there a std:bad_cast when I call otherMethod()?

Comment: Do you mean `Child c1;` instead of `Child c1();`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `std::vector` is declared as `std::vector<Parent>`. It holds only instances of `Parent` - when you insert the `Child1` and `Child2` instances, they get [sliced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

If you want to use a vector of polymorphic objects with a common base class of `Parent`, you need to use a container of pointers (or, for ease of lifetime and memory management, smart pointers).

Appropriate container types to consider include `std::vector<Parent*>`, `std::vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<Parent> >` and `boost::ptr_vector<Parent>`.

I'd recommend against the `std::vector<Parent*>` unless you're very comfortable with manual memory management.

---

*Also, you need to use public inheritance instead of private, and the base class must have a virtual destructor. I assume you left these out for brevity though.*

Answer (score 6):

When you say:

```
vector<Parent> vector_of_parent;
```

you create a vector of Parent - it cannot possibly contain Child objects. If you want a polymorphic C++ container, it must contain base class pointers. Your dynamic cast is failing because the things you apply it to are always Parent and never Child.

Also, it's not clear from your code, but in order to use dynamic_cast, your base class must contain at least one virtual function.

Comment: I've always thought that for non-polymorphic types dynamic_cast acts like static cast. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Basilevs: For a dynamic_cast to be valid, the argument must be convertible to the required type by upcast (trivially safe), must already be the same type as required, or must be a polymorphic type.

Answer (score 3):

```
vector<Parent> vector_of_parent;
```

You are creating a vector of `Parent` objects. Note that vector will always create a *copy* of the object passed. So when you do `vector_of_parent.push_back(c1);` a copy of c1 is created with a code like (for simplicity I am ignoring allocator) `T* pObj = new T(c1);`. Since here type of T is `Parent` , the copy created is of type `Parent`. So basically what happended was child objects is sliced to create parent object out of it. Now, if you try to dynamic_cast this `Parent` object to a `Child` type it will throw an exception.